# Como derivar um tipo a partir de um valor em TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Queria criar um type dinâmico. Algo como, por exemplo:

```
let cores = ['azul', 'vermelho', 'roxo'];
type cor = cores;
 
/* que deveria ser equivalente a 
type cor = 'azul' | 'vermelho' | 'roxo'*/
```

Para que ele mude de acordo com o array de cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não com valores dinâmicos, afinal, o verificador de tipos só é executado em tempo de compilação. É impossível esperar que ele faça qualquer tipo de julgamento ou inferência em um contexto dinâmico.

Você pode, entretanto, derivar um tipo através de um valor *constante*.

Para tanto, você não deve utilizar uma declaração `let`, mas sim `const`. Vejamos um exemplo simples:

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const; // A asserção `as const` garante que o tipo não mudará depois de declarado.

// Podemos, então, utilizar o operador de tipos `typeof` para derivar o tipo:
type MyArrType = typeof arr;
```

O tipo `MyArrType`, então, está definido como `readonly ["a", "b", "c"]`.

A união pode ser obtida indexando o tipo por `number`, assim:

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;

type MyElementType = typeof arr[number];
```

Se testar, verá que o *alias* `MyElementType` está definido para o tipo `"a" | "b" | "c"`.

Isso funciona porque o TypeScript retorna a união de todos os tipos indexáveis pelo tipo `number`. Como trata-se de um array, o tipo de cada elemento será unificado em um só.

- Ver mais sobre o [`typeof` estático](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#handbook-content) (não confundir com o [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) executado em tempo de execução).
- E sobre [*Index access types*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html#handbook-content).

Comment: Obrigadãão! Era isso mesmo.